# Namespace _STL has no member "regex"?

Tags: c++, regex

I already searched it and it looks like i dont need to use std::tr1::regex but std::regex is not working for me and i already am including ... Someone knows what could be happening?

```
string KingChatFilter::filter(string msg) {


            s3eDebugOutputString("Your Message!!");

            xingArray = txtReader("chatTest/restrict_words.txt");
            niceArray = txtReader("chatTest/replaces.txt");

            std::regex rx("/|\\*|\\)|\\(|\\.");
            // std::replace_if(msg.begin(), msg.end(), boost::is_any_of(", |"), '_');

            for(int i=0; i< msg.length(); ++i){
                if(msg.at(i) == 
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < xingArray.size(); i=i+1){
                if(msg == xingArray[i]){
                    msg = "amigao";
                }
            }

        return msg;
    }
```

I am getting the error in the regex rx line.

Comment: Are you sure that you have activated your compilers c++11 mode?

Comment: Maybe not, if i cant use c++11 what can i do? is there another expression?

Comment: What is your platform? OS? Compiler? Version? Compilation command?

Comment: Im using visual studio with marmalade in windows

Comment: Did you include the line *#include <regex>*? If so, did the compiler find the file?

Comment: Yes i did include and the compiler found it...

Comment: I wonder why you only answered half my queries. _All_ of them are required. This matters: I didn't ask just for fun.

Comment: Sorry i answered what i knew what is missing so i can get to you?

Comment: What is your platform? Compiler version? Compilation command?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? You shouldn't have to do anything to turn the support on if your Visual Studio version does support regex.

Comment: I just dont know but im sure im not using c++11, there isnt a way to use regex without it?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMrel

Comment: Could you please show the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: In std::regex rx("/|\\*|\\)|\\(|\\.");, "regex" is underlined red. If i just try to run i get "Cannot open include file: 'regex': No such file or directory". And if i put my mouse in the regex word i get "Namespace _STL has no member “regex”"

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to specify the `std::tr1` namespace? It's been a while since I used VS2010 so I don't remember when the MS implementation moved from `TR1` to `STD`.

Comment: So i should use like std::tr1::regex rx("/|\\*|\\)|\\(|\\."); right? 
But it says name followed by :: must be a class or a namespace name...
Do i need to include something?

Comment: I found some [example code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982821(v=vs.100).aspx) for VS2010 `<regex>` and they're just using `std::`. Can you try compiling the MSDN code to see if it works with your installed VS?

Comment: Actually one of the errors is for the #include <regex> the one that says fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'regex': No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you if it's not finding the `<regex>` header.

Comment: So there's nothing i can do?

Comment: You could look in the `include` directory to make sure there is a `regex` file, double check your spelling, possibly reinstall VS2010 and/or its updates.

Comment: When im writing #include <re... it appear the rest of the word regex and auto complete but when i compile i get this Cannot open include file: 'regex': No such file or directory...

Comment: autocomplete can sometimes do that, so just because autocomplete knows that there's a header called <regex> doesn't mean that VS can find it. I think reinstalling visual studio might be worth a try.